# expected primary-expression before '>' token

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

> Also duplicate of
>   [Two templates in C++: "expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778599/two-templates-in-c-expected-primary-expression-before-token)

Basically, what I am trying to do is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a523cefda60acbc):

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual int bar() = 0;
};

struct B {
    int bar() {return 1;}
};

struct C {
    int bar() {return 2;}
};


struct D {
    template <class T>
    static int foo() {
        T a;
        return a.bar();
    }
};


template<class T, class U>
int callFoo() {
    return T::foo<U> (); ///error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        std::cout << D::foo<B>() << std::endl; //This works of course
        std::cout << D::foo<C>() << std::endl; //This works of course
        std::cout << callFoo<D,B>() << std::endl;
        std::cout << callFoo<D,C>() << std::endl;
    }
```

How can I call a templated static method of a class which is parameter template of my function?

Comment: `return T::template foo<U> ();`